# Upcoming changes to YouTube Data API (Dislikes count)

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

We integrate with your app and a few days ago we received a [notification](https://blog.youtube/news-and-events/update-to-youtube/) about upcoming changes to YouTube that will impact the data available via the Data API.

The main difference is the Dislike count metric, which will no longer be accessible via the [v3 endpoint](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3). We obtain this metric through the [analytics endpoint](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics), for which there is no mention that this metric should no longer be obtained or that they would be affected in any way due to this change.

Can you please confirm that we will be able to obtain Dislike metrics normally via analytics endpoint?

Thank you for the clarification and best regards,
Ziga

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi. We would like to know if the Dislikes metric will not be affected on the analytics endpoint regarding this latest change?

Answer (score 2):

Dislikes ARE still counted! And you can get stats through Analytics - as well as v3 API *(for your **Own** video content of-course, **or** an app you created that an end-user has given permission to access their YouTube account data, that includes dislikes stat as well, for their videos)*.

You should know - Analytics API are **not** meant for *public* video stats. However, if you are in *desperate* need - you can apply to Google for an exemption.. explaining your use-cases. In that case, you will be applying for the v3 API.

From Google :

> *Developers: If you’re using the YouTube API for dislikes, you will no*
> *longer have access to public dislike data beginning on December 13th.*
> ***Your end users will still be able to view dislike data related to***
> ***their own content on authenticated API requests. You can apply for an***
> ***exemption (to have dislike data on non-authenticated calls)** as long as*
> *you don’t display or share dislike data with your end users.*